# Match a string against multiple regex patterns

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string.

I am thinking how to match this string against more than one regular expression effectively.

```
Example Input: ABCD
```

I'd like to match against these reg-ex patterns, and return `true` if at least one of them matches:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}

^[^\\d].*

([\\w&&[^b]])*
```

I am not sure how to match against multiple patterns at once. Can some one tell me how do we do it effectively?

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least for me). What do you mean by effectively? Do you want to check if input matches all regexes or just one is enough? Can you include beside input expected output?

Comment: I think that, first of all, you should define in natural language what kind of char sequences you want to be matched. Your example does not let us extract any pattern. Or, at best, here's a pattern that best match your input: "ABCD".

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Pshemo. Apologies. I have edited the question.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Does the input matter? Or is it just about matching against set of regexps?

Comment: @AndreiNicusan. I have one input string. And I have three regex patterns. I want to check if at least one of the regex pattern matches. Can you help.

Comment: `return rx1.matcher(s).matches() || rx2.matcher(s).matches() || ...;`

Comment: `for (Pattern rx : rxs) if rx.matcher(s).matches()) return true; return false;`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You should post that as an answer (with some more detail); I think you're the only person here that understood the question.

Comment: @JasonC Ironically, I am also the only person who voted to close as Unclear :)

Comment: @Patan I rephrased your question; apologies if this was presumptuous. It is a valid question, but the language was difficult to understand.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have just a few regexes, and they are all known at compile time, then this can be enough:

```
private static final Pattern
  rx1 = Pattern.compile("..."),
  rx2 = Pattern.compile("..."),
  ...;

return rx1.matcher(s).matches() || rx2.matcher(s).matches() || ...;
```

If there are more of them, or they are loaded at runtime, then use a list of patterns:

```
final List<Pattern> rxs = new ArrayList<>();


for (Pattern rx : rxs) if (rx.matcher(input).matches()) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: What is the most effective way : multiple matchers or multiple patterns joined by pipes ?

Comment: or you should say *more efficient?

Answer (score 30):

you can make one large regex out of the individual ones:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}|^[^\\d].*|([\\w&&[^b]])*
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for corrections, was unsure about the precedence of the | so I had wrapped it in parens to be safe

Comment: Since the parens also imply group capturing, they should be treated with care.

Comment: But then is there any way to know which one of my regex actually matched? I understand that the it may not be @patan's goal but I needed something similar.

Comment: @Sap you could wrap each expression  in parens and then use Matcher's `group()` method to determine which one matched, but you'd have to query it for each group. You're probably better off using individual regex's and a bunch of if else statements.

Answer (score 2):

like it was explained in ([Running multiple regex patterns on String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666725/running-multiple-regex-patterns-on-string/42892953#42892953)) it is better to concatenate each regex to one large regex and than run the matcher only one. This is an large improvement is you often reuse the regex.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid recreating instances of Pattern and Matcher classes you can create one of each and reuse them. To reuse `Matcher` class you can use `reset(newInput)` method. 
**Warning**: This approach is not thread safe. Use it only when you can guarantee that only one thread will be able to use this method, otherwise create separate instance of Matcher for each methods call.

This is one of possible code examples

```
private static Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("regex1").matcher("");
private static Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("regex2").matcher("");
private static Matcher m3 = Pattern.compile("regex3").matcher("");

public boolean matchesAtLeastOneRegex(String input) {
    return     m1.reset(input).matches() 
            || m2.reset(input).matches()
            || m3.reset(input).matches();
}
```

Comment: The whole purpose for the existence of `Matcher` is to create it each time to maintain state of a single match action. Your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True. Thanks for pointing that out. In one thread environment resetting Matcher seems little faster then recreating it, so decided to mention about it in my answer. Hope my edit makes my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative.
Note that one thing this doesn't do is return them in a specific order. But one could do that by sorting by m.start() for example.

```
private static HashMap<String, String> regs = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

...

```
    regs.put("COMMA", ",");
    regs.put("ID", "[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*");
    regs.put("SEMI", ";");
    regs.put("GETS", ":=");
    regs.put("DOT", "\\.");

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : regs.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(value).matcher("program var a, b, c; begin a := 0; end.");
        boolean f = m.find();
        while(f) 
        {
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
            System.out.print(m.start() + " ");
            System.out.println(m.end());
            f = m.find();
        }

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `effectively` means, but if it's about performance and you want to check a lot of strings, I'd go for this

```
...
static Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{3}");
static Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^[^\\d].*");
static Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("([\\w&&[^b]])*");

public static boolean test(String s){
   return p1.matcher(s).matches ? true: 
        p2.matcher(s).matches ? true: 
        p3.matcher(s).matches;
}
```

I'm not sure how it will affect performance, but combining them all in one regexp with `|` could also help.

Comment: This reinvents logical or and is missing parentheses. Why not use `p1.matcher(s).matches() || p2.matcher(s).matches() || p3.matcher(s).matches()`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't know what I was thinking 4 years ago.