# How to Match a String Against Multiple Regex Patterns in Java

Tags: java, regex

I understand how to match a single String against multiple regex patterns using the pipe symbol as explained in some of the answers to this question: [Match a string against multiple regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252297/match-a-string-against-multiple-regex-patterns)

My question is that when I have the following String:

```
this_isAnExample of What nav-input a-autoid-9-announce thisIsAnExampleToo
```

And I use the following regex to extract text:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*|(?<=_)[A-Za-z-]*
```

I am expecting to get the following matches:

```
is
An
Example
What
Is
An
Example
Too
```

But I actually get is:

```
isAnExample
What
Is
An
Example
Too
```

Basically the engine is automatically linking the word An with Example bec it matches the underscore pattern but I want it to treat them as two words (non greedy?) bec according to the other pattern there is another match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably ment the regex to be

```
[A-Z][a-z]*|(?<=_)[a-z-]*
```

The first part being lowercase word starting with uppercase letter, or the second: lowercase word preceded by underscore.

The part of your posted regex `(?<=_)[A-Za-z-]*` matches lower and upper case letters after underscore, i.e. does not stop matching when uppercase letter met, which should be in fact start of another word.

Comment: Just fyi. If input is just `_` it will find a match with empty string.

Comment: @anubhava you are right. Sadly the OP didnt describe what should be matched, he gave just one example... To match only non-empty strings replace `*` by `+` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this alternation regex to capture all the lower case text that is wither preceded by `_` OR mixed case text:

```
((?<=_)[a-z][a-z-]*|[A-Z][a-z]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF6kI1/2)